# DjangoRestFramework - How to send JSON object and HTML Template to the front-end at the same time?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, html-rendering

What I want is, if a user goes to this URL:

```
/user/22
```

then the front-end should render an HTML page for the user who's `pk` value is 22. This is my URLs.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.UserPageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And this is UserPageView:

```
class UserPageView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.get_object()
        return Response({'user': self.user}, template_name='user.html')
```

And this is my UserViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsCreationOrAuthenticated, IsWatchOrOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

Assuming 'user' is a JS object, I plan on using my DRF API by sending a get request using AngularJS to the following URL:

```
("/users/" + user.pk) // which leads to UserViewSet (which serializes the user object)
```

to get the information for that specific user. However, `user` is not a JSON object, it is a Django variable which I can use in the template using the Django template tags, like so: `{{ user }}`.

How do I get my DRF view to return JSON to the HTML template as well? What's the best way for me to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if there's any chance that it will work the way you're currently doing at, as the first met URL will always direct you to the `UserPageView`.

However, perhaps you should take a look at [DRF's format_suffixes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/).

With an additional format you can specify if you want to get the JSON or HTML representation of the user object.